# Observable android understanding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

I'm trying to understand how the observer pattern works in Android.

I've created this method to load a sample list of object, pushing each items to the subscriber and loading it to into the recyclerview.

I don't understand why if i load 10 items everything is working fine, but if i load 100/1000 or in general more items, the recyclerView is empty and onNext, onComplete are not fired.

```
private Observable<AppInfo> getAppList() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<AppInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super AppInfo> subscriber) {

            for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
                AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo(
                        "Test item "+i,
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher),
                        i
                );
                subscriber.onNext(appInfo);
            }

            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And this is how i use the Observable:

```
Observable<AppInfo> appInfoObserver = getAppList();

    appInfoObserver
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AppInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App List Load Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(AppInfo appInfo) {

                    if(mAppInfoList != null){
                        mAppInfoList.add(appInfo);

                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(appInfo.getAppPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks for the help and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not logging errors so if anything goes wrong you won't know (in this case you are probably forcing a `MissingBackpressureException` from the `observeOn` operator by sending it more than it requested). To be clear, in the subscriber:

```
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    // log or display error here!!
}
```

Don't use `Observable.create` at all if you can help it because you need to honour backpressure  or combine it with `.onBackpressureBuffer`.

The exception is that `Observable.create(new SyncOnSubscribe<T>(...))` is a good way to create an `Observable` if you can imagine your source as an iterator/enumeration.

To avoid using `Observable.create` in your example you could do this:

```
Observable
  .range(0, 10)
  .map(i -> new AppInfo(...))
```

or without lambda:

```
Observable
  .range(0, 10)
  .map(new Func1<Integer, AppInfo>() {
           @Override
           public AppInfo call(Integer n) {
               return new AppInfo(...);
           }
       });
```

Comment: Really good explanation! How can i avoid using lambda in the last snipped?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code is to heavy and its loading sync. Try to load your code inside a new thread, maybe you can use the observeOn() (i dont know exactally how rxjava works, but my guess is that this function defines the thread where the event occurs).

Comment: This observable is actually doing the job in a nel thread an pushing the result in the UI thread.. Is the purpose of them to be able to be flexible and scalable for threading.. That's why I still don't understand the issue